# Elixir "mix test" considers @doc examples as tests

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

Recently I wrote a the following function:

```
  @doc """
  Creates a new deck, shuffles its cards and retrieves a hand of
  cards from it.
  The `hand_size` argument indicates the size of the hand.

  ## Examples
      iex> {hand, _deck_remainder} = Cards.create_hand 2
      iex> hand
      ["Ace of Clubs", "Four of Hearts"]
  """
  def create_hand(hand_size) do
    create_deck
    |> shuffle
    |> deal(hand_size)
  end
```

Points to consider:

- `create_deck/0` returns a list of strings like `["Two of Clubs", "Four of Hearts"]`
- `shuffle/1` takes a list of strings and shuffles them using `Enum.shuffle/1`
- `deal/2` returns a tuple like `{["Ace of Spades"], ["Five of Clubs"]}`

Then I ran the `mix test` task and the following error appeared:

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFIw2.png)

It looks like mix test  is considering the examples in @doc  annotations as unit tests.

Due to `shuffle/1` randomly arranges the strings in the list, the example (as unit test) crashes.

I'd like to exclude those examples from `mix test`... Is it a good idea to do it? If so, how can I exclude them?

Comment: see https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.DocTest.html you need to disable `doctest` for your module. and in future, please, include errors as text, not image.

Comment: Thanks for the information and suggestion, @sobolevn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have copied some boilerplate test code that enables doctests by default. Like:

```
defmodule MyModule.Test do
  use ExUnit.Case, async: true
  doctest MyModule
end
```

Remove the doctest bit and you should be fine. You can of course also format the comment to not look like a doctest :-)

Comment: Thank you =D !! I hadn't noticed that line in the module.